# VBA Search column for specific String and import the formula of a cell in the same row as search to another sheet

Tags: vba, search, loops, import, multiple-columns

I have two sheets in excel. The goal is to take ratings from one sheet and make it into a table on another sheet. I need to make a code that can search though a column on the first sheet for each department name and then for each search result it finds grab the value from a different column in the same row as the search result and put that value in a cell on the table Sheet.

Example: The first sheet is set up a little like this but with much more data

```
Department     Rating Category    Rating
   CM               RX1.1           FI
   CM               RX1.2           FI
  PPQA              RX1.1           LI
  PPQA              RX1.4           NI
```

So what I need to do is create a loop to that will search the Department column and grab the rating in the same row as the search and import it into a table on another sheet.

Example of output for other sheet:

```
      RX1.1  RX1.2  RX1.3  RX1.4
CM      FI    FI     N/A    N/A
PPQA    LI    N/A    N/A    NI
ETC.    N/A   N/A    N/A    N/A
ETC.    N/A   N/A    N/A    N/A
```

I understand I will have to write if statements to make sure the data goes into the right cell. I can figure that out. I just need help on searching for a string in one column and taking the value of the string in a different column but same row as the searched string.

I have a decent amount of programming experience, mostly with java, but I am slightly new to VBA so any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Heres what I've got so far after messing around with it for a while. Take note I am new to VBA and I am just trying things the way I think they will work for now. I'm sure there are much more practical ways to get at what I am trying to so any suggestions would be great.

```
Sub MainCode()

'Call defineProAreaArr
'Dim arrCount As Integer
'Dim Result As Variant
Set r = Worksheets("Summary all PIIDB")
With r
    'For M = 0 To 19
        Call FindEntryArea
End With
End Sub


Sub FindEntryArea()

Dim EntryCell As Variant
Dim x As String
With Worksheets("Summary all PIIDB").Range("T:T")
    Set d = .Find("REQM", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set x = Worksheets("Summary all PIIDB").Range.Cells(d.Row, 2).Value
End With
Dim eRow As Integer 'Entry Row
Dim eCol As Integer 'Entry Column
Dim WrongRow As Boolean
If Worksheets("Summary all PIIDB").Cells(d.Row, 19).Value = 0 Then
    WrongRow = True
    MsgBox "Area not valid"
    Exit Sub
End If
eRow = Worksheets("CHART").Range("A2:A21").Find("REQM", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
eCol = Worksheets("CHART").Range("B1:AG1").Find(x, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
Worksheets("CHART").Cells(eRow, eCol) = Worksheets("Summary all PIIDB").Cells(d.Row, 19).Formula
End Sub
```

Still very early into making this. Going to add a loop to search through all departments and all once I get FindEntryArea() working.

As of right now I keep getting an Object Required error on:

```
Set x = Worksheets("Summary all PIIDB").Range.Cells(d.Row, 2).Value
```

Thank You

Comment: Does it need to be VBA? Cause you can do the same thing with Vlookup function

Comment: Could I use Vlookup to automate the whole table?

Comment: hmm but the table is not as simple as it is on the example in the column there are certain rows where the department column will match the search but I will need an if statement to check if another cell in that row has a certain String and that will determine whether I take the rating from that row or not. I think I'd be better of creating this in VBA unless you believe there is a better solution.

Comment: i prefer vba over the formulas but the easiest solution would be to actually use formulas. if you want vba you have to provide your code that doesnt work so we can fix it ;)

Comment: Ok I will work on it, hopefully I will have something to put up here in a couple hours. thanks for the help so far.

Comment: no problem. come back with some code if you encounter problems

Comment: Added code to review would love some feedback. Thank You

Comment: check out the code i wrote for you. please leave feedback wheter it solved your problem